# Redis LRANGE Pop Atomicity

Tags: redis, atomic, redis-cluster

I am having a redis data store in which there are unique keys stored. Now my app server will send multiple requests to redis to get some 100 keys from start and I am planning to use [LRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/LRANGE) command for the same.

But my requirement is that each request should receive unique set of keys,which means that if one request goes to redis for 100 keys then those keys will never be returned to any request in future.

As I saw that redis operations are atomic, so can i assume that if there multiple requests coming from app server at same time to redis, as redis is single thrreaded, so it will execute  `LRANGE mylist 0 100` and once it is completed (means once 100 keys taken and removes from List), only then next request will be processed, so atomicity is inbuild,is it correct?
Is it ever possible under any circumstance that two requests can get same 100 keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the command you actually want is [`LPOP`](https://redis.io/commands/lpop), since [`LRANGE`](https://redis.io/commands/lrange) doesn't remove anything from the list.

```
LPOP mylist 101
```

And, yes, this command is atomic, so no two clients will receive the same elements.